# How to store query error message in variable in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, psycopg2

I am running a query where it is showing error that I need to store in a variable and used that message in if-else condition. Please help me to solve this?

Example:

```
query = "ALTER DATASHARE table1 ADD TABLE table2;"
cur.execute(query)
```

error:

```
Relation table2 is already added to the datashare table1
```

I want to store above error in variable and use in if-else condition.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look to try/except/finally in python

Comment: This is not standard Postgres as it does not have `DATASHARE`. What database are you working with and what is it's version? **Add info as update to question**.